# How to find the controller which handles a url in Prestashop

Tags: php, controller, prestashop-1.6

I'm kind of new to Prestashop and I decided to practice on a project that's completed already (Prestashop 1.6.1.18). The thing is the project is pretty large and sometimes I get lost in the folder structure. I come from Codeigniter and Symfony and thought that might have been useful thinking Prestashop too had a similar URL->Controller->View mechanics but so far I've been going on for a while now trying to find the controller (and controller function) which handles this specific URL:

```
http://localhost/content/discount-products
```

I would appreciate some insight on how URL end points make their way to a function in a controller. Are they registered somewhere (Routes.php in Codeigniter, config files in Symfony). Should I be able to now this from that URL alone?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Use this code on hookDisplayHeader

```
p($this->context->controller);
```

This code gives you all information about current controller on both BO and FO